# Countability of the range of the mapping of an uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Given a mapping f: R->R, what properties must f have in order for its range to be countably infinite? I'm personally not sure, especially in terms of formalization, but ideas of non-monotonicity or some construction of countably infinite equivalence classes come to mind.

For context, in quantum mechanics it's said that a system's energy can only take discrete values, but this confuses me since energy is defined as the sum of a function of position and a function of momentum, which can both take any real value. The indexing of the sets doesn't make much sense to me, especially since the kinetic energy, the function of momentum, is very clearly uncountable since it's strictly monotonic. So even if the potential energy has a countable range, it doesn't make sense that the total energy would be since the union of a countable set and an uncountable set is uncountable. Like I said, I'm more concerned with the question I asked above rather than this confusion that created it, as I'm sure an answer will either lead me in the right direction, or at least give me the means to reasonably formulate a new question- so don't worry about addressing this.

Any answers or information are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is necessary that $f$ must be identically a constant, or discontinuous on every interval $(a,b)$.